# Confused about proof by contradition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In proof by contradiction, I can understand how it works when the hypothesis leads to a clearly false proposition. e.g., if we want to prove $P$, we assume $\neg P$ and show that $\neg P \implies ... \implies Q$, but we know that $\neg Q$ and since we just proved that $\neg Q \implies P$, $P$ is true.

However, I get confused when the hypothesis leads to its own negation. In other words, we have $\neg P \implies ... \implies Q \implies P$. I can't help but feel that $\neg P\implies P$ is just something meaningless that we can't use to conclude anything. We could say that since $Q\implies P$, $\neg P \implies \neg Q \implies P$, but again what this is saying is $\neg P \implies P$.

A good example of this type of proof is [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/dij-proof.html) where the assumption that the selected vertex does not have its shortest path determined leads to the conclusion that it does indeed have its shortest path set.

Comment: You were going so well unto you gto to "And since we just proved..." No you didn't, you proved $\lnot P\implies Q$.

Comment: A contradiction by any other name would smell as sweet.

Comment: If $\neg P \implies Q$ then $\neg Q \implies P$. ?

Comment: Why is that the case? The only way to prove that is (hint) by contradiction!

Comment: Yeah I see your point

Answer (score 2):

Let $Q$ be the statement $P\land\lnot P$. We know that $Q$ is false.

Then if you have $\lnot P\implies P$ then you have $\lnot P\implies (P\land \lnot P)$, which is $P\implies Q$. But we know $Q$ is false, so $P$ is false.

Indeed, every proof by contradiction can be written as:

$$P\implies(A\land \lnot A)$$

for some predicate $A$.

In your case, you knew that $\lnot Q$ is true, so you can conclude from $P\implies Q$ that $P\implies (Q\land\lnot Q)$.

In the case of $P\implies \lnot P$, you have $A$ the same as $P$. But you still reach a contradiction - you know that something is both true and not true.